# Query to get ids that are either only in one location or both

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get ids from this simple table that are both in location A and B or are only in A or B

[image]

example outcome: 
a22 is unique for location A only
a23 is both in A and B
etc.

Comment: `both in location A and B or are only in A or B` ... this would match _every_ record.  Are you asking for two queries here?  Have you tried answering this yourself yet?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT unique_id
    ,count(unique_id)
FROM (
    SELECT a.id AS locationA
        ,b.id AS locationB
        ,CASE WHEN locationA IS NULL THEN 'onlyb' WHEN locationB IS NULL THEN 'onlya' ELSE 'both' END AS unique_id
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT id
            ,location
        FROM table
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND location = 'A'
        ) a
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id
            ,location
        FROM table
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND location = 'B'
        ) b ON a.id = b.id
    )
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 3):

To get ids that are in both locations

```
select id
from your_table
where location in ('A','B')
group by id
having count(distinct location) = 2
```

To get unique ids

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having count(distinct location) = 1
```

Comment: i assume the unique ids query also needs a filter like `where location in ('A','B')` ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Why? They appear in just one location, no matter in which one. I added the `where` clause to the first query in case there are other locations like `C`, `D`...

Comment: indeed i should have said can have instead of need. i focust on "How do I get ids from this simple table that are both in location A and B or are only in A or B" that more or less implies a filter on 'A' and 'B' that's why i said it i geuss.  The first query indeed needs that filter the second can indeed go without..

Answer (score 3):

We can try the following query to find those `id` which have both locations:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
WHERE location IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(location) <> MAX(location);
```

To find those `id` having only location `A`:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(location) = MAX(location) AND MIN(location) = 'A';
```

The above queries are written as such so that we might place an index on `(id, location)`.  MySQL should be able to take advantage of this index for both queries.

Comment: I think the question is ill defined, but you are covering both cases.

Comment: @TheImpaler For writing SQL queries, I am quite "ill" (referring to hip hop lingo meaning of the word) :P

Comment: Thanks. So in the second query how would I get count of IDs that are only in location A  AND are not in location B. Sorry for my bad phrasing of question.

Comment: I couldnt make your query work in my case but can you look at my query I posted?